# Form edition for a N:M relationship with extra fields is not working

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms, symfony-2.5

I'm working on a form that handle N:M relationship with an extra parameter (extra field/column). This is what I've done until now:

In `OrdersType.php` form:

```
class OrdersType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        // $builder fields

        // $builder fields only need on edit form not in create
        if ($options['curr_action'] !== NULL)
        {
            $builder
                    // other $builder fields
                    ->add("orderProducts", "collection", array(
                        'type' => new OrdersHasProductType(),
                        'allow_add' => true,
                        'allow_delete' => true,
                        'by_reference' => false
            ));
        }
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Tanane\FrontendBundle\Entity\Orders',
            'render_fieldset' => FALSE,
            'show_legend' => FALSE,
            'intention' => 'orders_form',
            'curr_action' => NULL
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'orders';
    }

}
```

In `OrderHasProductType.php`:

```
class OrdersHasProductType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
                ->add('product', 'text', array(
                    'required' => FALSE,
                    'label' => FALSE
                ))
                ->add('amount', 'text', array(
                    'required' => TRUE,
                    'label' => FALSE
        ));
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Tanane\FrontendBundle\Entity\OrderHasProduct',
            'intention' => 'order_has_product'
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'order_has_product';
    }

}
```

And finally this is `Orders.php` and `OrdersHasProduct.php` entities:

```
class Orders {
    use IdentifiedAutogeneratedEntityTrait;
    // rest of fields for the entity 

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="OrderHasProduct", mappedBy="order", cascade={"all"}) 
     */
    protected $orderProducts;

    protected $products;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="deletedAt", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $deletedAt;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->orderProducts = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->products = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getOrderProducts()
    {
        return $this->orderProducts;
    }

    public function getDeletedAt()
    {
        return $this->deletedAt;
    }

    public function setDeletedAt($deletedAt)
    {
        $this->deletedAt = $deletedAt;
    }

    public function getProduct()
    {
        $products = new ArrayCollection();

        foreach ($this->orderProducts as $op)
        {
            $products[] = $op->getProduct();
        }

        return $products;
    }

    public function setProduct($products)
    {
        foreach ($products as $p)
        {
            $ohp = new OrderHasProduct();
            $ohp->setOrder($this);
            $ohp->setProduct($p);

            $this->addPo($ohp);
        }
    }

    public function getOrder()
    {
        return $this;
    }

    public function addPo($ProductOrder)
    {
        $this->orderProducts[] = $ProductOrder;
    }

    public function removePo($ProductOrder)
    {
        return $this->orderProducts->removeElement($ProductOrder);
    }

}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="order_has_product")
 * @Gedmo\SoftDeleteable(fieldName="deletedAt")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"order", "product"})
 */
class OrderHasProduct {
    use IdentifiedAutogeneratedEntityTrait;

    /**
     * Hook timestampable behavior
     * updates createdAt, updatedAt fields
     */
    use TimestampableEntity;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\Tanane\FrontendBundle\Entity\Orders", inversedBy="orderProducts")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="general_orders_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $order;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\Tanane\ProductBundle\Entity\Product", inversedBy="orderProducts")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $product;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $amount;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="deletedAt", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $deletedAt;

    public function setOrder(\Tanane\FrontendBundle\Entity\Orders $order)
    {
        $this->order = $order;
    }

    public function getOrder()
    {
        return $this->order;
    }

    public function setProduct(\Tanane\ProductBundle\Entity\Product $product)
    {
        $this->product = $product;
    }

    public function getProduct()
    {
        return $this->product;
    }

    public function setAmount($amount)
    {
        $this->amount = $amount;
    }

    public function getAmount()
    {
        return $this->amount;
    }

    public function getDeletedAt()
    {
        return $this->deletedAt;
    }

    public function setDeletedAt($deletedAt)
    {
        $this->deletedAt = $deletedAt;
    }

}
```

But when I try to edit a order with this code in my controller:

```
public function editAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $order = $em->getRepository('FrontendBundle:Orders')->find($id);
    $type = $order->getPerson()->getPersonType() === 1 ? "natural" : "legal";

    $params = explode('::', $request->attributes->get('_controller'));
    $actionName = substr($params[1], 0, -6);

    $orderForm = $this->createForm(new OrdersType(), $order, array('action' => '#', 'method' => 'POST', 'register_type' => $type, 'curr_action' => $actionName));

    return array(
        "form" => $orderForm->createView(),
        'id' => $id,
        'entity' => $order
    );
}
```

I get this error:

> The form's view data is expected to be of type scalar, array or an
>   instance of \ArrayAccess, but is an instance of class
>   Proxies__CG__\Tanane\ProductBundle\Entity\Product. You can avoid this
>   error by setting the "data_class" option to
>   "Proxies__CG__\Tanane\ProductBundle\Entity\Product" or by adding a
>   view transformer that transforms an instance of class
>   Proxies__CG__\Tanane\ProductBundle\Entity\Product to scalar, array or
>   an instance of \ArrayAccess.

And I don't find or know how to fix it, can any give me some help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is happening because this code

```
class OrdersHasProductType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
                ->add('product', 'text', array(
                    'required' => FALSE,
                    'label' => FALSE
                ))
        ));
    }
    //...
}
```

means that Symfony is expecting "product" to be a field of type "text", but when it calls `getProduct()` on the OrderHasProduct it gets a Product object (or a Doctrine Proxy to a Product, since it's not been loaded at that point).  Symfony Fields inherit from Form/AbstractType, so they're essentially Forms in their own right, with just one field, hence the error message.

The solution is either to make that field of type "entity", or to create a different method which only gives the name of the Product, e.g. `getProductName()` on OrderHasProduct, and then use that as the data behind the field.

Comment: Hi @frumious and thanks for all the replies you leave here (this one and the other two you answered). The reason what I use `text` instead `entity` is because I'm using a Select2 component which through AJAX call gets products from DB and I don't want the typically select component rendered by Symfony if I use a `entity` type, if you know any solution around this then yes I can use `entity` without problems

Comment: Ah, OK.  Can you use [the entity field `property` option](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#property) to get the output you want?

Comment: Hmmm I'm not sure if `property` will help in some way, did you have a idea around this?

Comment: Possibly not...  What exactly do you need to pass to your Select2? Could you give an example of rendered HTML?

Comment: it's online take a look [here](http://tanane.com/tanane/web/order/natural) find this string "Ofertas realizadas a facturar" and there you'll see what I'm talking about (sorry for the spanish translation) if you habe any doubt ping me again I'm here

Comment: That link isn't working right now.  But anyway, let me see if I've got the idea: you're using Select2 to get the product list via AJAX, so you don't need it to be supplied by your Controller at all, apart from just the name of the current product in a text box?  I think that in that case you need to either add new `getProductName()` and `setProductName()` methods to OrderHasProduct, which are there just to map to an OrderHasProductType field.  Those methods would need to inspect or replace the Product entity appropriately.

Comment: Or alternatively create a completely new set of ViewModel classes which exist only to give data to and receive data from your View, I've done this when what I want to display on the page doesn't map well to my entity hierarchy.  You have to translate between Entities and ViewModel in the Controller.  This is more work, but can be best depending on the situation.